# apex:selectCheckboxes Command button stops working when an option is selected unless you click the button at least once before selecting any options

Tags: visualforce, action, selectcheckboxes

I have the following page:

```
<apex:page controller="testPageController">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:selectCheckboxes value="{!selectedContacts}">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!contacts}" />
        </apex:selectCheckboxes>

        <apex:commandButton value="Test" action="{!testAction}" />
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class testPageController {
    public List<SelectOption> contacts {get; set;}

    public List<String> selectedContacts {get; set;}

    public testPageController () {
        this.contacts = new List<SelectOption>();

        for (contact con : [
            SELECT Id, FirstName
            FROM Contact 
            LIMIT 10
        ]) {
            this.contacts.add(new SelectOption(con.Id, con.FirstName));
        }
    }

    public void testAction() {
        system.debug('Hello World!');
    }
}
```

Using apex version 43 in my developer org. Also reproduced in our companies sandbox org.

### Steps to reproduce

- preview page from dev console
- select any number of options
- click test
- View Debug Logs

### Expected

`Hello World` displays in logs

### Actual

Nothing displayed in logs

### End User Workaround

- preview page from dev console
- **do not select any options**
- click test
- View Debug Logs
- Hello World displays
- select any number of options
- click test
- View Debug Logs
- Hello World displays

Can anyone reproduce this? Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `selectedContacts` controller property doesn't contain an instance of a list after construction.

When you click the button, the VF page posts the data to the server which then tries to store your selections in a null list.

Initialize the list in the constructor and it works just fine.

```
public class testPageController {
    public List<SelectOption> contacts {get; set;}

    public List<String> selectedContacts {get; set;}

    public testPageController () {
        this.contacts = new List<SelectOption>();
        this.selectedContacts = new List<String>(); // need an instance of the list!

        for (contact con : [
            SELECT Id, FirstName
            FROM Contact 
            LIMIT 10
        ]) {
            this.contacts.add(new SelectOption(con.Id, con.FirstName));
        }
    }

    public void testAction() {
        system.debug('Hello World!');
    }
}
```

Comment: Strange you'd figure my apex:pageMessages tag would have displayed something for that (the one I have in the actual page, as the sample code obviously doesn't have one)